# mysql markers not showing on map

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

good night , im trying to show markers on a map with JSON but im not able to and i don't know why , i can see the map and can move around it but not even one marker is showing ,

```
<?php
require("config.php");
/* lat/lng data will be added to this array */
$locations=array();
$query =  $db->query('SELECT * FROM inmuebles');
    while( $row = $query->fetch() ){

        $longitude = $row['long'];                              
        $latitude = $row['lat'];

        /* Each row is added as a new array */
        $locations[]=array('lat'=>$latitude, 'long'=>$longitude );
    }
    /* Convert data to json */
    $markers = json_encode( $locations );

    echo $markers;
  ?>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
    echo "var markers=$markers;\n";

?>
var map;
    var markersArray = [];

function initMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-16.5338955,-68.0656364);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, lat, long;
    var json=JSON.parse( markers );

    for( var o in json ){

        lat = json[ o ].lat;
        long=json[ o ].long;

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
            map: map
        }); 
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e){
            infowindow.setContent( this.name );
            infowindow.open( map, this );
        }.bind( marker ) );
    }
}
</script>
```

the output of $markers is

```
[{"lat":"-16.52629052070058","long":"-68.0797004699707"},{"lat":"-16.500122130208325","long":"-68.12089920043945"},{"lat":"-16.54307592346882","long":"-68.06425094604492"}]
```

thanks in advance i've been trying really hard to see where the mistake is

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','waru','olairhead154','inmueble');
?>
 <?php
require("config.php");
/* lat/lng data will be added to this array */
$locations=array();
$query =  $db->query('SELECT * FROM inmuebles');
    while( $row = $query->fetch() ){

        $longitude = $row['long'];                              
        $latitude = $row['lat'];

        /* Each row is added as a new array */
        $locations[]=array('lat'=>$latitude, 'long'=>$longitude );
    }
    /* Convert data to json */
    $markers = json_encode( $locations );


    echo $markers;
 ?>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 <?php
    echo "var markers=$markers;\n";

?>
var map;
    var markersArray = [];

function initMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-16.5338955,-68.0656364);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    var markers = '<?= json_encode($markers) ?>';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, lat, long;
    var json=markers;
    for( var o in json ){

        lat = json[ o ].lat;
        long=json[ o ].long;

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
            map: map
        }); 
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e){
            infowindow.setContent( this.name );
            infowindow.open( map, this );
        }.bind( marker ) );
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
</script>
```

this are the changes i made but still no marker shown im really new to this please be patient with me

thanks

Comment: The "output of $markers" is not a JSON string, it is a javascript array, `JSON.parse` won't work on it.  Pass it directly into your loop. ([Proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/khe9eqj4/1/))

Comment: @geocodezip tried what you told me but i can't still see markers , can you help me a little bit more?
var markers = '<?= json_encode($markers) ?>';
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, lat, long;
        var json=markers;
        for( var o in json ){
            lat = json[ o ].lat;
            long=json[ o ].long;

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
                map: map
            });

Comment: 1. please don't post (large amounts of) code in the comments, it isn't readable ([edit] your question to address comments).  2.  if I read what you posted, it isn't what I "told you", please look at the fiddle.

Comment: @geocodezip i edited the post and now shows the code better please help me i can't seem to find what to do

Comment: managed to do it , was a dumb mistake of mine ... thanks a lot for the answears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better if you'll just echo your **$markers** in **var markers** together with the **json_encode()** function. After that, you can just create a new js variable **var markersJson** and the value is **JSON.parse(markers)** (you need to parse it as JSON, otherwise it will give you an error). From there, you can just iterate through the array using javascript **.map()** function (Higher-order function) and display it as Google Maps marker.

For more info regarding Google Maps Marker, please check **[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)** link.

Sample coordinates from table inmuebles:

```
<?php 
   $markers = array( 
         array( 'lat' => -16.52629052070058, 'lng' => -68.0797004699707 ),
         array( 'lat' => -16.500122130208325, 'lng' => -68.12089920043945 ),
         array( 'lat' => -16.54307592346882, 'lng' => -68.06425094604492 )
   );
?>
```

Echo $markers with json_encode() to var markers:

```
var markers = '<?= json_encode($markers) ?>';
```

Parse markers as json:

```
var markersJson = JSON.parse(markers);
```

Iterate through the array and display the coordinates as Google Maps Markers

```
var plotMarkers = markersJson.map(function(value, index){
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position : new google.maps.LatLng( value.lat, value.lng ),
   map: map,
   title : 'Hello'
 });
 return marker;
});
```

Whole code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Maps - PHP Markers Implementation</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html,body {
                height:100%;
            }
            body {
                width:100%;
            }
            #map_canvas {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
         <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php 
                $markers = array( 
                    array( 'lat' => -16.52629052070058, 'lng' => -68.0797004699707 ),
                    array( 'lat' => -16.500122130208325, 'lng' => -68.12089920043945 ),
                    array( 'lat' => -16.54307592346882, 'lng' => -68.06425094604492 )
                );
            ?>  
            function initMap() {
                var markers = '<?= json_encode($markers) ?>';
                var markersJson = JSON.parse(markers);
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-16.5338955,-68.0656364);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                };  
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
                var plotMarkers = markersJson.map(function(value, index){
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position : new google.maps.LatLng( value.lat, value.lng ),
                        map: map,
                        title : 'Hello'
                    });
                    return marker;
                });
            }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i manage to do this with a for loop and the mysql database? sorry for bothering

Comment: Are you getting results from your query?

Comment: when i echo the $markers variable i get [{"lat":"-16.52629052070058","long":"-68.0797004699707"},{"lat":"-16.500122130208325","long":"-68.12089920043945"},{"lat":"-16.54307592346882","long":"-68.06425094604492"}]
 but looks like it is not entering the script  thanks in advance

Comment: managed to do it , it was a dumb mistake declaring $markers twice thanks a lot for the answear

Comment: Hahahaha! No problem mate.